# Solr Filter Query and Type Casting

Tags: solr, solrnet

One of the fields in my query is generated using the query below:

```
ImportAge:ceil(div(ms(NOW, ImportDate),mul(24,mul(60,mul(60,1000)))))
```

All it does is give me the number of days since the import date. The problem is that this returns as a double but the expected type in our data objects is int32 so we get a cast exception when performing the query with solrNet.

Is there a way to type cast the result of the function query?

Comment: Easiest solution: make your property a `float`, then cast it within your code as needed.

Comment: That was going to be the second option if I couldn't cast it with solr.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Solr function queries...